# what is the optimal way i should design my table?

Tags: mysql, database-design

i have a table with 4 fields:

- standard auto_increment id
- user_id(two entries can be present with same user_id)
- product_id(two entries can be present with same product id)
- (both can be present in two rows)
- expiry (a datetime field used to remove the row after the expirt time has passed)
  now i have two needs:
- query the table top get all rows whose expiry time has passed
- query the table for a specific user to get all his entries
  is there a way to design the table to make both of these accesses fast?
  thankyou in advance :)

Comment: *"[To] make both of these accesses fast"* that's what indexes are for. The table structure should be designed to be valid and easy to query. In your case what is the reason for multiple user_id/product_id? Is that to define an association between the user-product pair? If yes then `(user_id, product_id)` would make a good primary key instead of the autoinc column. (each pair can only be there once and neither can be NULL).

Comment: Show us the tentative `SELECT` statements; we can provide the optimal indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
create table table1 
( user_id ... 
, product_id ...
, expiry ...
, primary key ( user_id, product_id )
, index( expiry )
);
```

Your Natural, primary key is `user_id` and `product_id` - no need for an artificial "id" column here.  Put `user_id` first as you want to query by it and this allows for an Index-Range scan.
An index on `expiry` makes date-based queries faster.

Comment: Doesn't "both can be present in two rows" say that the pair is not Unique, hence cannot be the PK?